# A Darboux integral

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow  R$ ,
proof by Darboux sums:
f is integrable if and only if for every $ε>0$ there exist functions $h,g:[a,b] \rightarrow$ R, that are integrable such that for exery x $\in[a,b]$:
$$h(x)\leq f(x) \leq g(x)$$
and:
$$\int_a^b (g(x)-h(x))<ε$$

Comment: Please make subject lines about the mathematic content of the post, and not about you.

Comment: This is also a repost.

Comment: @Cornman If you have a link to a previous answer to this question then you can flag this question as a duplicate. In case this thread is not closed, OP what have you tried? Do you understand what is being asked on you? For instance, one direction of this equivalence is quite easy.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
For a given partition $\mathcal{P}=\{a=a_0<\ldots<x_n=b$} define
$$\begin{align}
h(x)&=\sum^n_{k=1}\big(\inf_{t\in[x_{j-1},x_j]}f(t)\big)\mathbb{1}_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}(x)\\
g(x)&=\sum^n_{k=1}\big(\sup_{t\in[x_{j-1},x_j]}f(t)\big)\mathbb{1}_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}(x)
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathbb{1}_A(x)$ stands for the function that is $1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise. Clearly $h\leq f\leq g$. The functions $h$ and $g$ are step functions and clearly Riemann integrable. Can you finish from this?

Comment: what about ε? how you defined g and h without it?
and what about the other direction wich I think it's harder than the first
thanks

Comment: From the necessary and sufficient conditions of Riemann integrability, give $\varepsilon>0$ there is a partition $P_\varepsilon$ of $[a,b]$ fir which $U*f,P_\varepsilon)-L(f,P_\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$. The $h_\varepsilon$ and $g_\varepsilon$ are the correponding step functions related to $P_\varepsilon$.